# Drupal 7 hook_form_alter and submitting the form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, drupal

I added some custom field so that i can get more information when someone registers into the website but i want to alter one field on the form. I created a module which has a hook_form_alter function so that i can alter the field_first_name of the registration form. here is the code

```
function user_registration_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
if ($form_id == 'user_register_form'){

    $form['field_first_name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('First Name'),
        '#description' => t('Enter your first name.'),
        '#maxlength' => 255,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        );



}
if (isset($form['actions']['submit'])) {
 $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] ='user_registration_form_submit';
   }

}
```

I also created a the function which handles the form submission.

```
function user_registration_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state)
{


$fe_id = db_insert('field_revision_field_first_name')
    ->fields(array(
        'field_first_name_value' => $form_state['value']['field_first_name'],
        ))->execute();
    drupal_set_message(t('your form entry has been added'));
}
```

My problem is that when i submit the form and i check the user details. i find that the first name details does not exist in the database or when i login as the administrator and click on the 'people' link. i find that all information is are submitted except the first name field which i am trying to alter. I also tried to submit the form without the form submit function but it still doesn't work.

and i get the following error message if i add the form_submit function

> Notice: Undefined index: value in user_registration_form_submit() (line 37 of /var/www/html/lite/sites/all/modules/user_regestration/user_registration.module).
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'entity_id'
>   doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO
>   {field_revision_field_first_name} (field_first_name_value) VALUES
>   (:db_insert_placeholder_0); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => ) in
>   user_registration_form_submit() (line 38 of
>   /var/www/html/lite/sites/all/modules/user_regestration/user_registration.module).

THIS IS LINE 37 AND 38 OF MY CODE

```
'field_first_name_value' => $form_state['value']['field_first_name'],
))->execute();
```

I am creating the module on localhost first before i push it to the live website

Comment: I had made a typo on line 37. it is suppose to be "values" instead of "value" but now i am getting the following error......."PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'entity_id' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO {field_revision_field_first_name} (field_first_name_value) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => john ) in user_registration_form_submit() (line 38 of /var/www/html/lite/sites/all/modules/user_regestration/user_registration.module)‌​"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's **values** not value.

Why don't you use a module providing this functionality, like [profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) ?

The user is not created in your submithandler, so either you save it:

```
function foo_user_register_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
    $edit = array(
          'name' => $form_state['values']['name'], 
          'pass' => user_password(),
          'mail' => $form_state['values']['mail'],
          'init' => $form_state['values']['mail'], 
          'status' => 1, 
          'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
          'field_first_name' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $form_state['values']['field_first_name']))),
    );
    user_save(drupal_anonymous_user(), $edit);
}
```

For more details see the [docs](https://www.drupal.org/node/1063598).

Or you could try to add a custom submit handler, which would be fired after the user is created, in form_alter:

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'your_custom_submit_handler_function';
```

In there the user should already be created. so:

```
function your_custom_submit_handler_function(&$form, &$form_state)
    {
        $fe_id = db_insert('field_revision_field_first_name')
        ->fields(array(
            'field_first_name_value' => $form_state['values']['field_first_name'],
            ))->execute();
        drupal_set_message(t('your form entry has been added'));
    }
```

> But keep in mind, that this custom inserting maybe needs some more
>   code, here you only add the revision entry ..

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing in an entity_id, and your database schema isn't defining a default one. The database expects one, and so it is failing, and it is failing on insert - which is your lines 37 and 38. It has absolutely nothing to do with your first name part.

Basically, Drupal (technically MySQL, or whatever your database backend is) doesn't know *what* entity you're trying to associate that field with.

Please look at the table that you're actually putting the information into and ensure that the schema either has a default set

Something like:

```
db_insert('field_revision_field_first_name')
        ->fields(array(
            'field_first_name_value' => $form_state['values']['field_first_name'],
'entity_id' => 1,
            ))->execute();
```

Would probably work better for you. There may be other required fields. I recommend taking a look at your database schema.

You also shouldn't have to define a custom form for this - you can add fields to users, and also there is profile2 as another poster mentioned.